# Knockoutjs only validate chind class

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I use Knockoutjs 3.0.0 and Knockoutjs-Validate, most time they work good. Now I have problem when I try to validate partial View Model.
Like this:

```
 function DataViewModel() {
      var self = this;

      self.username = ko.observable("").extend({ required: {message:"User name is required!" }});
      self.password = ko.observable().extend({ required: {message:"Password is required!" }});

      self.login = function () {

          if (self.isValid()) {
              self.errors.showAllMessages();
              return false;
          }
           $("#loginform").submit();
      };
  }
```

and I also have Page Viewmodel which control page attribute.

```
  function PageViewModel(){
    var self=this;
    self.contentheader=ko.observable("Login");
    self.usernamelabel = ko.observable("User Name");
    self.passwordlabel = ko.observable("Password");
  }
```

I create ViewModel like this:

```
 function ViewModel()
  {
    var self=this;
    self.data= ko.validatedObservable(new DataViewModel());
    self.page= new PageViewModel();
  }
```

finally I bind to KO
      var vm = new ViewModel();
      ko.applyBindings(vm);

Why I do program like this is:
in DataViewModel, I store data which will be pass or load from server, Page view model I  control this page behave, I should do validate for DataViewModel when user submit data to server. But it doesn't work, I saw KO model raise error like this

```
 TypeError: obsv is undefined
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can handle the validation for your `DataViewModel` within that model. Add an observable within your model to track the validation, like so

`self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);`

and change your `DataViewModel` instance in your primary viewmodel to be a normal `ko.observable` instead of a validated observable. I've [made a fiddle with the complete code](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/ygk2m/1/).

Comment: This works. But I got another trouble. When user name and password restore from browser, knockoutjs-validate doesn't work.

Comment: @Ericyu67 Could you elaborate (maybe post some of the code that restores those field values in an edit to your original question)?

Comment: I tested your sample code, it does work only if I key in some value. But when I try copy/paste value to textbox, it can't trigger validate. Maybe here is not right place to ask this question.